# SQLite.Interop.DLL How to use non managed DLL

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I would like to use System.Data.SQLite with an wpf application.
So I dowloaded the files [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and add the reference to System.Data.SQLite downloaded.

Then I write the code

```
 SQLiteConnection connex = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Toto\Desktop\Test.sqlite;");
        connex.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteCommand command = connex.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TEST";
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = command;
        da.Fill(dt);
        connex.Close();
```

But It doesn't work.. When I try to open the connexion, it says that it is impossible to find the SQLite.Interop.dll.. No problem I have this one but impossible to add reference to it because it is an unmanaged DLL.

So, if someone is used to use SQLite and ADO.NET I'm looking for advices..

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should close your connection using the `using` statement

Comment: I know thanks this was just for testing..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to copy the unmanaged DLL to the same folder as your EXE.

Comment: You may want to add the unmanaged DLL as a file to the project so you can set Copy to Output Directory.